# How do I add space between the ticklabels and the axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, xticks, yticks

I've increased the font of my ticklabels successfully, but now they're too close to the axis.  I'd like to add a little breathing room between the ticklabels and the axis.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It looks like matplotlib respects these settings as rcParams:

```
pylab.rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='8'
pylab.rcParams['ytick.major.pad']='8'
```

Set those *before* you create any figures and you should be fine.

I've looked at the source code and there doesn't appear to be any other way to set them programmatically.  (tick.set_pad() looks like it tries to do the right thing, but the padding seems to be set when the Ticks are constructed and can't be changed after that.)

Comment: instead of setting the rcParams *before* creating any figures, users can also use a context manager: `with plt.rc_context({"xtick.major.pad": 10}):` Any code that is indented below this line will be plotted with the settings specified in the rc_context.

Answer (score 139):

If you don't want to change the spacing globally (by editing your rcParams), and want a cleaner approach, try this:

`ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', pad=15)`

or for just x axis

`ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=15)`

or the y axis

`ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=15)`

Comment: This much easier than iterating through ticks for a single plot. Thanks! For a single axis you can also use: `ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=n)`

Comment: Quite difficult for an unexperienced reader to understand what ax is. If I get it with  ax = plt.gca(), then the command only moves the labels.

Comment: Thanks, this works well for radial subplots as well (Adds space to the outer labels)

Comment: To get the current axis, you might need to use plt.gca() instead of ax-

plt.gca().tick_params(axis='both', which='major', pad=15)

Answer (score 24):

This can be done using `set_pad` but you then have to reset the label...

```
for tick in ax.get_xaxis().get_major_ticks():
    tick.set_pad(8.)
    tick.label1 = tick._get_text1()
```

Comment: I would suggest that ugly here is somewhat irrelevant and that this is still a good solution.  There are many occasions when you're not just making one plot on the same figure.  This means rcParams is not a solution because you want to avoid global settings.

Comment: @MikeGM: In retrospect, I agree with you for the reasons you mention.  I'll take out my description of this as ugly, though the label reset isn't exactly elegant.  Thanks for you comment.

Comment: Nice answer. A 'pretty' solution is to have a style file with `ytick.major.pad: 5.0`, `axes.labelpad: 10.0` and other related settings. Getting it to one's taste will waste many valuable hours however.

Answer (score 3):

- As with many canonical questions, this one isn't very specific, and doesn't have a reproducible example, so here's an example for figure labels and title.
- The other answers are great for `axes` plots, but there are other options for a `figure`, which can all be positioned by specifying the `x=` and `y=` parameter.

  - [`fig.suptitle`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.suptitle)
  - [`fig.supxlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.supxlabel)
  - [`fig.supylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.supylabel)
- Example from [Figure labels: suptitle, supxlabel, supylabel](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/figure_title.html)

```py
from matplotlib.cbook import get_sample_data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 5, figsize=(8, 5), constrained_layout=True,
                        sharex=True, sharey=True)

fname = get_sample_data('percent_bachelors_degrees_women_usa.csv',
                        asfileobj=False)
gender_degree_data = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=',', names=True)

majors = ['Health Professions', 'Public Administration', 'Education',
          'Psychology', 'Foreign Languages', 'English',
          'Art and Performance', 'Biology',
          'Agriculture', 'Business',
          'Math and Statistics', 'Architecture', 'Physical Sciences',
          'Computer Science', 'Engineering']

for nn, ax in enumerate(axs.flat):
    ax.set_xlim(1969.5, 2011.1)
    column = majors[nn]
    column_rec_name = column.replace('\n', '_').replace(' ', '_')

    line, = ax.plot('Year', column_rec_name, data=gender_degree_data, lw=2.5)
    ax.set_title(column, fontsize='small', loc='left', y=1.05)  # move the axes title
    ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
    ax.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', pad=15)  # move the tick labels
    ax.grid()

fig.supxlabel('Year', y=-0.15)  # with adjusted position
fig.supylabel('Percent Degrees Awarded To Women', x=-0.05)  # with adjusted position
fig.suptitle('Majors', y=1.15)  # with adjusted position

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, especially useful to see the output, which helped me see the setting I needed right away. Instead of sticking styles inside loops, I find it useful to set up a style file, with things like `ytick.major.pad: 5`. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `labelpad = n`, when labelling your axes, for giving some space between ticklabels and the axis.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.xlabel("X-axis Label", labelpad = 10)
plt.ylabel("Y-axis Label", labelpad = 10)
```