# How to reduce spacing between plot and xticks using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

As shown in the figure

[image]

by the arrows, I'd like to decrease the spacing between plot and xticks.
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969867/how-do-i-add-space-between-the-ticklabels-and-the-axes-in-matplotlib

Comment: Take a look at http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params. The 'pad' parameter controls the spacing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are three ways to set the distance between ticklabels and the axis:

```
ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=10)
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10
plt.xlabel("your labels go here", labelpad=10)
```

And here's another one:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['xtick.major.pad']='8'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt and detailed reply.
 "ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=10)" solved my issue.
Best regards.

Comment: @OrsoPusterla it'll be better if next time You'll include minimal working code reprodcing the problem at hand. You should also show You tried to solve the problem Youself. If You need to post picture You can post it directly at stackoverflow (there's picture button when You type in question).