# How to space out the x values with uneven axis in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(448312,497812,100)
y = np.linspace(7188379,7986879,1598)
z = np.random.rand(100,1598)
interp_method = "sinc"
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.imshow(z, interpolation=interp_method, cmap='viridis', extent= (x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]))
axs.set_title(str(interp_method))
plt.show()

# the image is on https://imgur.com/ZYIkqAw
```

The previous code produces a heatmap that isn't quite readable, is there a way to "expand" the x axis without creating interpolated values?
I tried several approaches but all failed I changed figsize (failed), i changed the axes with:

```
axs=plt.axes([.65, .6,  10, 10], facecolor='k',aspect='equal')
```

but it ultimately is impossible to widen the heatmap enough to make it clearer.
I don't really want to create empty values in the x axis and use a plot to interpolate them. Is there a way to "zoom" in to x axis and make the plot seem square?

I checked the following links thoroughly but i couldn't get something that could've helped:

[How to change spacing between ticks in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863375/how-to-change-spacing-between-ticks-in-matplotlib)

[How do I add space between the ticklabels and the axes in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969867/how-do-i-add-space-between-the-ticklabels-and-the-axes-in-matplotlib)

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html

Thanks in advance everyone :)
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Did you play with the `aspect` argument of `imshow`?

Comment: yes i've already tried "equal" without results..

Comment: The "auto" choice seems to be right!!! thanks a lot mate!  https://imgur.com/lwDuPJ0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a square plot:

```
axs.imshow(z, interpolation=interp_method, cmap='viridis', extent= (x[0], x[-1], y[0], y[-1]), aspect=“auto”)
```

Note it is the same code as yours, just added the `aspect=“auto”` argument to `imshow()`.

Here's the image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2GFD.jpg