# How to reduce distance between axis and tick labels , and align tick labels properly to axis?

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, axis

I am using a sequence of barplot on 3D projection to generate 3D bar plot as per code which is given below. But, axis tick labels are displayed much far from axis line. How can I reduce distance between axis and axis tick labels?  Further tick labels are not seems properly aligned with axis.

code snap is given below:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,2),dpi=300)
plt.rc('font', size=4) 

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect(aspect=None, zoom=0.8) #--to resolve axis label cut-off problem
z=np.arange(len(list(df_3d)))
print("z",z)
print(list(df_3d))
for n, i in enumerate(df_3d):
    # print ('n',n)
    xs = np.arange(len(df_3d[i]))
    ys = [i for i in df_3d[i]]
    zs = z[n]

    cs = colors[n]
    # print (' xs:', xs,'ys:', ys, 'zs',zs, ' cs: ',cs)
    ax.bar(xs, ys, zs, zdir='y', color=cs, alpha=0.8)


yaxislabels=[]
for i in list(df_3d):
    yaxislabels.append("")
    yaxislabels.append(i)
ax.set_yticklabels(yaxislabels)  #(list(df_3d))

ax.set_xlabel(axislabels[0],labelpad=0.5)
ax.set_ylabel(axislabels[1],labelpad=0.5)
ax.set_zlabel(axislabels[2],rotation=90,labelpad=0.5)

plt.show()
```

How can I reduce distance between axis and axis labels ?

[image: Seaborn 3D barPlot Image]

I do not find any alternate solution. Please, help.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what `df_3d` is ?

Answer (score 1):

As in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29524883/1862861), you should just be able to use the `pad` argument to [`tick_params`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html), e.g.,

```py
ax.tick_params(axis="y", pad=2)
ax.tick_params(axis="z", pad=2)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", pad=2)
```

Play about with the value passed to `pad` and see what looks best (2 looked quite good in an example I mocked up myself).

Comment: It is not working. Still there is distance between axis and axis tick labels

Comment: Does it have any effect at all for you? If you put in different pad values for each axis, do you notice a difference?